# Debit and credit amounts

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, business-intelligence, helper

I am dealing with a statement of account. Depending on the description " inv??? Or receipt??"  The amount from sheet1 should he debited or credited in sheet2. The problem is that each invoice has a unique name so Vlookup doesn't work

[image]

Comment: You can add a new column with left(D8, 3) to isolate the first 3 characters of each description (replace D8 with cell coordinates). This means that there won't be unique names anymore, all invoices would be "inv", all Receipts would be "Rec".

Comment: What does sheet1 look like? Try using the Snipping tool for your screen shots they will show up better.

Comment: Do you mean you want that if the description data in sheet1 has a text inv, then put the amount in sheet2 column credit - and if the description data in sheet1 has a text receipt, then put the amount in sheet2 column debit ?